# xfbml or html5 not working if tag not executed when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, xfbml, facebook-likebox

I have a site with image gallery. The same template and files are used by all the template pages.
On photo page xfbml like works. On album page, which has a lightbox effect and fb like code generated by javascript when user clicks something, nothing appears, even though i can see the code is correct. html tag and sdk are included fine.

do i need to tell the script to reinitialise when the javascript is generated?

any help apreciated..

shaun

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `FB.XFBML.parse(someElement)` where `someElement` contains your XFBML tag.